# Assign dynamic value to a variable on reasizing window - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, resize

I need to assign a dynamic value to a variable. Specifically, I would like to assign the window width and detect if window has been resized.

To assign window width I know it would be as follows:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
```

But I dont't know how to get window width when it has been resized, so that variable would always have the current window width.

Is that possible? I can't find the way to do that!

Than you very much in advanced!

Jur.

Comment: add a resize event on the window or body

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RtP45/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this to check when the window has been resized, why not add an event handler to the window resize event?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    alert("resized");
});
```

If you only want the function to run once when the resizing has finished, try this:

```
var resizeTimer;
var windowWidth;
$(window).resize(function() {
   clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
   resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
       windowWidth = $(window).width();
       alert("New width: " + windowWidth);
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But what i need is to run the variable out from de .resize function, to be a global variable, is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Declare `var WindowWidth;` at the top of the page (outside the resize event) then set it on the event fire.

Comment: @user1722662 No problem, I've just updated my answer. Thanks webnoob

Comment: And how would I do that? What I am doing is moving left position of a div based on window width and if I resize the window the width variable doesnt change so the left position is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this event:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
}
```